# Time series reference - Estimating ARIMA models using the Yule-Walker equations and Durbin-Levinson algorithm

Tags: time-series, estimation, arima, references, numerics

I am doing some research related to time-series analysis, and hence was trying to find some good examples of implementations of the common estimation algorithms. For example, I wanted to fit some simple ARMA(2,2) models where I simulate some data and then use common time series algorithms to recover the parameters or coefficients on the different terms. However, I have not been able to find a decent book that has the code to implement algorithms like the Yule-Walker equations, or the Durbin-Levinson algorithm, etc.

I was reading Shumway and Stoffer, and the ideas seem intuitive enough, but the notation is extremely dense and hard to fathom. Hence I was wondering if anyone knew of any books that had code to implement some of these common algorithms? I have googled around and looked through a few different books including Brockwell and Davis, but with no luck. Even something with Pseudocode would help.

Does anyone know of any good blog posts or books with actual code for the algorithms. Most of the time I find books that refer to their own packages for implementation. So they say, the code to run the Durbin-Levinson algorithm is `DurbinLevinson()` but they don't actually indicate how to write that function or the numerical properties of writing the estimation routine in one way or another.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Perhaps Hamilton ["Time Series Analysis"](https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691042893/time-series-analysis) (1994) has them? Just guessing.

Comment: I have Hamilton, so I can take a look. Hamilton does not seem to have any code though, since it was 1994, but the notation seems a little nicer. I am surprised there is not more on numerical methods for statistics, considering how much numerical methods stuff is available for say ordinary and partial differential equations.

Comment: I was not sure which level of implementation you were interested in. After your comment, I now think Hamilton (1994) is not the right reference.

Comment: I was looking at the Kitagawa book, which does not have code but seems to have more details on estimation. I might have to go to the original papers to find some of the implementation details I want, but was hoping I would not have to do that. Hamilton is good too, but does not have code. It would be nice just to see a code implementation and then recovery of coefficients for some simulated data using different estimation methods.